# How to read a file character by character in Go

Tags: json, parsing, go, io

I have some large json files I want to parse, and I want to avoid loading all of the data into memory at once.  I'd like a function/loop that can return me each character one at a time.

I found [this example](http://golangcookbook.com/chapters/strings/processing/) for iterating over words in a string, and [the ScanRunes](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#ScanRunes) function in the bufio package looks like it could return a character at a time.  I also had the `ReadRune` function from bufio mostly working, but that felt like a pretty heavy approach.

### EDIT

I compared 3 approaches.  All used a loop to pull content from either a bufio.Reader or a bufio.Scanner.

1. Read runes in a loop using `.ReadRune` on a `bufio.Reader`. Checked for errors from the call to `.ReadRune`.
2. Read bytes from a `bufio.Scanner` after calling `.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)` on the scanner. Called `.Scan` and [`.Bytes`](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Bytes) on each iteration, checking `.Scan` call for errors.
3. Same as #2 but read text from a `bufio.Scanner` instead of bytes using [`.Text`](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Text).  Instead of joining a slice of runes with `string([]runes)`, I joined an slice of strings with `strings.Join([]strings, "")` to form the final blobs of text.

The timing for 10 runs of each on a 23 MB json file was:

1. `0.65 s`
2. `2.40 s`
3. `0.97 s`

So it looks like `ReadRune` is not too bad after all.  It also results in smaller less verbose call because each rune is fetched in 1 operation (`.ReadRune`) instead of 2 (`.Scan` and `.Bytes`).

Comment: Why do you think it is heavy? I would recommend try and see whether it works for you or not.

Comment: @AlexAtNet Calling that function manually every time seemed like a weird approach instead of using some sort of build in iterator (which is what `ScanRunes` provides, I think). Also, I had to do some casting of strings into runes to check for sequences of characters, then runes back into strings to save portions of output.  Something that looks like the first example I linked to but works with bufio would be better. Really the answer is that it smelled funny - a little too complicated for something that should be very simple.

Comment: See my answer. It is quite simple, I think...

Comment: @BravadaZadada Excellent point about all *valid* JSON being in the ASCII range and being able to read byte by byte.  Once of my concerns was using bufio to read into a byte array and accidentally cutting off half a utf-8 character.  Shows my ignorance about encodings. :/

Comment: @BravadaZadada Yeah I meant using something like `Read` or `ReadBytes` to get from file to byte array then breaking into runes after that. I think I could have run into issues if I did it that way.  But looking at the functions that takes bytes and grab runes, it looks like they will complain if the input is invalid anyway, so I was probably a little premature with that concern.

Comment: @BravadaZadada Also: this is the second question of mine you've helped with in 2 days. Special thanks for that!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just read each rune one by one in the loop... [See example](http://play.golang.org/p/11sY76fcc1)

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

var text = `
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog #1.
Быстрая коричневая лиса перепрыгнула через ленивую собаку.
`

func main() {
    r := bufio.NewReader(strings.NewReader(text))
    for {
        if c, sz, err := r.ReadRune(); err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            } else {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%q [%d]\n", string(c), sz)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using this solution (just calling readRune in a loop, which is what I had before). I just didn't know that calling "string" on a slice of runes cast that into a string and I thought it would be slow. I want to give @AlexAtNet's solution a try tomorrow to compare before I accept an answer.

Answer (score 9):

This code reads runes from the input. No cast is necessary, and it is iterator-like:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    in := `{"sample":"json string"}`

    s := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(in))
    s.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)

    for s.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(s.Text())
    }
}
```

Comment: Alex - I ended up accepting tez's solution because it came out faster and a little simpler.  But thanks a lot - your solution was what I *thought* I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

if it's just about the memory size. In the upcoming release (really soon) there is going to be a token style enhancement of the json decoder :
you can see it here

https://tip.golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Token

Comment: Yeah, I did know about that. It is def. about the memory size, but also, for our data, we can get away with less complex parsing by assuming that "{" and "}" never show up unmatched in json content, and get away with simple counting to find object boundaries.  That makes breaking up the objects very fast. Also it means we don't have to wait for that release!